# c++: why char c = 0xff and int n = c+1 get the result of 100?

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering why n = 0 here?

```
char c = 0xff;
    int n = c+1;
    cout << n << endl;
    system("pause");
```

1) c = 0xff
2) 0xff + 1 = 0x100.

Could you explain?

Comment: If you wrap those statements in `int main() {...}`, I think you should get either 0 or 256.  Where did 100 come from?

Comment: So, in the title you ask "why is it 100?", while in the body of the question you ask "why is n = 0?". So, what is it? 100? Or 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming an unsigned `char` type, `0xff` would give the decimal value 255. Add one to that and you get 256, or `0x100` or 256. This would be printed out as `100` if you had manipulated `std::cout` to print in hex with `std::cout << std::hex;`

Assuming an **8-bit** signed `char`, `0xff` would overflow, giving -1. Add 1 to that and you would get 0.

Comment: There are 10 types of people in the world those who use binary and those who don't

Comment: Their ninja edit broke your answer.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I was starting to wonder if I was going mad...

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood what's going on here.  Rolled back my changes...

Answer (score 6):

Your platform apparently uses *signed* `char` type. When you initialize it with `0xFF`, it overflows and leads to implementation-defined behavior. Your `c` ends up being equal to `-1`. And when you add `1` to `-1`, you get `0`. Nothing unusual here.

Declare your `c` as `unsigned char`, and the resultant `n` value will be `0x100`, which is probably what you expected.

Comment: But (s)he doesn't get 0...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: The title of the question contradicts the body of the question. In the body (s)he said that `n` is 0.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'm deleting my answer...

Comment: @AndreyT: if he used `unsigned char`, the resultant `n` would be `0x100`, _which would overflow_ resulting in `0` again.  Right?

Comment: @MooingDuck except that the result is promoted to `int`, so it doesn't overflow.

Comment: @juanchopanza: oh right, ignore me